# Make Userprofile and make the user view its profile information

Tags: django

How to make the user view its profile information, after logging, even if another user is logged in in a different browser,and suggestion

Comment: Please rephrase your question, doesn't make much sense. If you want to redirect after login, a simple view function will do but I'm not sure that's what you are after.

Comment: This post shows no research or effort on your part.

Comment: please show us what you tried so far

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking the easiest way then you should put this in your settings.py file

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/profile/user/'
```

where profile is you app to control data from user and user/ is just the url to find the function that response to request.

```
def show_user_profile(request):

    template_name = 'your_template_name_here.html'
    user = request.user    

    return render(request, template_name, {'user':user})
```

after that you can render you template using context variable.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>{{user.first_name}}</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

you url should look like

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'profile'

urlpatterns = [
    path('user/', views.show_user_profile, name="show_user_profile"),
   ]
```

you must read the documentation about login and authentication. [Using the Django authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/)